# Network manager not taking dns-search into account for VPN, GNOME Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, gnome3, networkmanager

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

I have a VPN configured with the following ipv4 config (I replaced the real domain names by fake ones)

```
[ipv4]
dns=19.0.0.1;19.0.0.2;19.0.0.3;
dns-search=domain1.fr;domain2.fr;domain3.com;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto
```

The dns config seems ok because I am able to access internal web site, so their name is corretly resolved by dns I guess.

But if I want to connect to a server using ssh like

`ssh user@server1`

Then it is not able to find the host without the FQN like

`ssh user@server1.domain1.fr`

It seems the dns-search option is not taken into account whereas from the doc `nm-settings` it seems that I am doing everything fine

```
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────────┤
   │ignore-auto-dns    │ boolean          │ FALSE         │ When "method" is set   │
   │                   │                  │               │ to "auto" and this     │
   │                   │                  │               │ property to TRUE,      │
   │                   │                  │               │ automatically          │
   │                   │                  │               │ configured nameservers │
   │                   │                  │               │ and search domains are │
   │                   │                  │               │ ignored and only       │
   │                   │                  │               │ nameservers and search │
   │                   │                  │               │ domains specified in   │
   │                   │                  │               │ the "dns" and          │
   │                   │                  │               │ "dns-search"           │
   │                   │                  │               │ properties, if any,    │
   │                   │                  │               │ are used.              │
   ├───────────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────────┤
```

Note that under GNOME this dns-search option is not available through the UI interface, I cannot understand why.

Comment: At the end of the day, NetworkManager is only configuring your network, VPN and name resolution. If name resolution does not work, look at /etc/resolve.conf to find out what is wrong there. Btw. not every UI exposes all options, e.g. gnome-control-center may not show dns-searches.

Comment: Thx for the remark, I should have mentionned that I have been trying to figure out how to manage the resolv.conf in any possible way, with and without resolvconf. Right now I am appending my config using the resolvconf tail file but this is ugly IMO. I am looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. I've added dns servers and they are being propagated to /etc/resolv.conf automatically by NetworkManager (although I had to change /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and comment out the line 'dns=dnsmasq'). However, no matter what I do, dns-search is not being propagated.

Comment: I ended up writing some ugly sh script overriding my resolve.conf for info...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my vpn. This is what worked for me:

1. Change *dns-search* in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
2. Restart NetworkManager. `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`
3. Activate vpn
4. `systemd-resolve --status`

I assume the config files are loaded when the NetworkManager service starts and not when you start your vpn connection.